# Confusion about the efficiency of sorting algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have read on the book about selection/insertion/shell sorting algorithms, and according to the book, generally, selection sort is slower than insertion sort which is slower than shell sort. However, I ran a few tests using Python only to find that selection sort is the fastest! I can't figure out why, the only reason I can think of is that there are too many swaps between elements of the list.

Here's the code I used for testing:

```
import random
import time



lst = [ random.randint(1,10000) for _ in xrange(10000) ]

def timeit(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        t1 = time.time()
        result = f(*args)
        t2 = time.time()
        print 'time: %f' %(t2 - t1) 
        return result
    return wrapper

@timeit
def selectionSort(lst):
    for i in xrange(len(lst)):
        minNum = lst[i]
        for j in xrange(i+1, len(lst)):
            if lst[j] < minNum:
                minNum = lst[j]
        lst[i], minNum = minNum, lst[i]
    return lst

@timeit
def insertionSort(lst):
    for i in xrange(len(lst)):
        for j in xrange(i, 0, -1):
            if lst[j] < lst[j-1]:
                lst[j], lst[j-1] = lst[j-1], lst[j]
            else:
                break
    return lst

@timeit
def shellSort(lst):
    h = 1
    while (h < len(lst)//3):
        h = h * 3 + 1


    while (h >= 1):
        for i in xrange(h, len(lst)):
            for j in xrange(i, h-1, -h):  
                if lst[j] < lst[j-h]:
                    lst[j], lst[j-h] = lst[j-h], lst[j]
                else:
                    break
        h //= 3
    return lst


selectionSort(lst[:])
insertionSort(lst[:])
shellSort(lst[:])
```

The result on my machine is as follows:

```
[linuxfish@Arch week2]$./sortAlgorithms.py 
time: 4.533489
time: 22.247762
time: 12.867564
```

This is the results after I've added the two lines code, pretty amazing..

```
time: 4.937693
time: 16.773167
time: 0.179526
```

The sorting method was adapted from [this book](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) by Robert Sedgewick, and I think I implemented the algorithms exactly the same as what the book was said although the original algorithms in the book was written in Java

Comment: You should use `//` if you want integer division. In that way the expression will behave correctly even under python3 or when using `from __future__ import division`. (besides making the intention clearer).

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for pointing that out! Any insights about the question?

Comment: I'm not sure about why you are getting this result but you may want to check the time consumed per swap operation. Note that the number of swaps needed for a selection sort is just O(N), not O(N^2).

Comment: can you show your result?

Comment: That's not an insertion sort!  The inner loop of the insertion sort should bail out once it's found the right place to insert the element.  Instead, you're making as many comparisons as a bubble sort would.  As a test, try it on an already sorted list: insertion sort should be O(n) in that case, but your version is still O(n^2).

Comment: You're also missing bailout code for the Shell sort:  look back at the Java original, and you'll see that the inner loop starts with: `for (int j = i; j >= h && less(a[j], a[j-h]); j -= h)`.  Note the `less(...)` condition there:  you don't have any equivalent to that in your Python code.

Comment: It seems that both insertion and shell sort are improperly implemented.

Comment: @SlavaBacherikov yes, you are right. I forgot one or two lines of code.. Anyway, I have updated the code above

Comment: Your insertion sort does quite a lot quite a lot of accesses - try something like `val = lst[i]; for j in xrange(i, 0, -1) if val < lst[j-1] lst[j] = lst[j-1] else lst[j] = val; break` (just to give an idea, pardon my rusty python). Oh, and if your confusion is resolved, consider answering yourself and accepting that answer (both seems to be perfectly OK with stackoverflow/StackExchange).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://bigocheatsheet.com/ sort section. and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort It seems the data you use causes different behaviour because only select sort is stable one.

Here is a the info:

```
               | Best   |  Average | Worst
Select Sort    | O(n^2) | O(n^2)   |  O(n^2)

Insertion Sort | O(n)   | O(n^2)   | O(n^2)

Shell sort     | O(nlogn) | depends on the gap | O(n^2)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NKN The link doesn't answer the question.